# Only first record picked when i use str_replace inside a codeigniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using `str_replace` to replace some text if it occurs in a message but it only picks the first record when i use inside codeigiter query.

When i try printing out the variable holding the replaced message,i can see it works but not inside the codeigniter query.

```
$combined_message = $t_message . ' ' . $t_signature;
$current_id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
$findme   = '_names';
    $pos = strpos($combined_message, $findme);

    if ($pos === false) {
        echo "string not found";
        }

    else {
    $rowcount = $this->db->count_all('send_q');
    $query = $this->db->query("select sender from send_q");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $new_message = str_replace("_names",$row->sender,$combined_message);
    echo $new_message . "<br/>";//this echos all corectly

    /**
    Insert Into Outgoing Table
    */
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO outgoing_sms (dest_msisdn,text_message,sender_name,service_id)
    SELECT receiver,"'.$new_message.'","'.$das_sender_name.'", "'.$das_service_id.'" FROM send_q');

     /**
     Insert Into Logs Table
     */
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO all_sent_messages (the_receiver_name,the_receiver_number,the_message,the_status,the_user_id,the_timestamp)
     SELECT distinct sender,receiver,"'.$new_message.'","sent", "'.$current_id.'",now() FROM send_q');
     /**
     Delete From send queue where user_id = $user-id
     */
     $this->db->query('delete from send_q where user_id = "'.$current_id.'"');

    }
    }
```

Why is the `$new_message` not being included in the query?.

Comment: ...because you have double-quotes around your field names.

Comment: @stealthyninja nope,i tried single quotes too and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace`

sample

```
$string = 'this will be this is not this was being was this';

$test = preg_replace('/this/', '1', $string);

var_dump($test);
```

Result:

`string '1 will be 1 is not 1 was being was 1' (length=36)`

add `i` to the pattern to search for `'/this/i'` to make it case insensitive